# Using VLOOKUP to look into 2 columns from 2 seperate spreadsheets, apply formatting if found in second column?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am trying to use VLOOKUP on Google Sheets to look into different sheets, one having 'good' inventory, the other having 'damaged' inventory. If value found on the sheet with 'damaged' inventory, I want to highlight the 'LOT # SERIAL #" column for that row so the counters and analysts can identify these.

I have tried combining the VLOOKUPS, basically inserting into the argument another instant to look elsewhere. However, I am more interested in a fucntion that can look for the 'LOT & SERIAL #' in the 'Damaged' database sheet, and highlight it in red if a match is found, without affecting my other VLOOKUPS for 'DESCRIPTION', 'CLASS 1', etc.

My sheet works fine until I try to do a VLOOKUP on 'LOT & SERIAL #'. I know I must be doing it wrong and it's more of a data validation rule, but how can I acomplish this by looking into the 'LOT & SERIAL #' of those other two sheets, and if matched to a 'Damaged' product, highlight in red?

Anybody knows how to achieve this with User Defined Functions only? Any help would be much appreciated it.

Sample sheet (it already has everything else I needed to do set):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kd3-8I_isB6s4hHhx4GO-vOB3NkWAZwO2R8OeP3aAgA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a way to do the data validation from another sheet, see below:

=match(G:G,indirect("CTRDW Damage Slabs DATABASE!H:H"),0)